# WordPress Woo Manual XML Import - Can I use URL instead of ID for thumbnail post meta?

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a little plugin that generates an xml file to batch upload variable woocommerce products. I'd like to be able to switch the featured image reference for the post to pick up a URL instead of the image ID to avoid me manually grabbing and inputting all the product/gallery images. I've tried hardcoding URLs in but to no avail, despite their being picked up for other fields such as permalinks. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[3553]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
```

**Update:**
Looks like a solution is here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140467/how-to-add-featured-thumbnail-into-import-xml

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is in this post which outlines the additional xml required to both call in the attachments and correspond them to the post/product. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140467/how-to-add-featured-thumbnail-into-import-xml